# Cutsomize the ESRI Silverlight Feature Data Form?

Tags: silverlight, arcgis, esri

I have a Feature Data Grid  where if i click on the attributes row, a Feature Data Form opens up for editing that particular rows attributes. I would like to change the Textbox width and height or change to Multilne Mode of the Feature Dat form. In short a template of my own.

How can i achieve this?  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The data form is open source and available on github. So you can customize it however you want it.
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-toolkit-sl-wpf

Comment: hi Morten, Thank you for the reply..But I am a newbie ..can you please explain how to use the content in the link provided. Thanks ...

Comment: Hi morten,  Ok I have made change to the ESRI.ARCGIS.Client.ToolKit changing the feature data form.cs  textbox to richtextbox with overflow. WHat should i do now..How can i make this change show up in my project...Please gudie ..Thank you

Comment: After you made the change, you build the toolkit. In your original project replace the Toolkit reference to the one you just built (or include the toolkit project in your solution and create a reference to the project directly)